# Find Total based on group by of two mongo field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have collection data like this -

```
{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "branch_id" : "1",
    "total" : 100,
},
{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "branch_id" : "1",
    "total" : 200
},
{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "branch_id" : "3",
    "total" : 1400
},
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "branch_id" : "1",
    "total" : 100
},
{
    "user_id" : "2",
    "branch_id" : "1",
    "total" : 100
},
```

I am looking to get output in the below format -

```
[
{
    "user_id":"1",
    "branch_id":"1",
    "grand_total":"300"
},
{
    "user_id":"1",
    "branch_id":"3",
    "grand_total":"1400"
},
{
    "user_id":"2",
    "branch_id":"1",
    "grand_total":"200"
}
]
```

I have tried a mongo aggregate query, but the query gives output as undefined.

Basically I need to get per user wise per branch wise the total points he has earned.

Here is what I have tried but not working -

```
Collection.aggregate(
                    {
                        "$group": {
                            "_id": "$user_id",
                            "nameCount": { "$sum": 1 },
                            "branch_id": {
                                "$sum": {
                                    "$cond": [ {"$branch_id":{"$ne":null}} ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$project": {
                            "_id": 0, 
                            "name": "$_id",
                            "nameCount": 1,
                            "branch_id":1            
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aggregation pipeline has to look like this:

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            user_id: "$user_id",
            branch_id: "$branch_id"
        },
        "grand_total": {
            "$sum": "$total"
        },

    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "user_id": "$_id.user_id",
        "branch_id": "$_id.branch_id",
        "total": "$grand_total"
    }
}
```

---

Inside your `_id` field in your `"$group"` pipeline you add the fields that you want to group your documents by. If you only want to group by one field you can write it as follows:

```
{"$group": {
        "_id": "$user_id"
        }
}
```

If you have multiple fields you want to group by (like it seems in your case) then you write it as follows:

```
{"$group": {
        "_id": {
           user_id: "$user_id",
           branch_id: "$branch_id"
           }
        }
}
```

Every aggregation pipeline changes your document. So, in your `$group` if you call the sum of all totals like that `"grand_total"`

```
"grand_total": {
            "$sum": "$total"
        }
```

then in your `$project` pipeline that field `total` doesn't exist anymore. But instead we created a new field (`grand_total`) that is the sum.